# Why first Gatling request is slower?

Tags: java, performance, load-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I have a Gatling scenario where I'm calling the Gatling demo app endpoint. I noticed that the first request is taking a higher time to respond to.
For example:

```
public class OneEndpointSimulation extends Simulation {

HttpProtocolBuilder httpProtocol = http
        .baseUrl("http://computer-database.gatling.io")
        .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
        .doNotTrackHeader("1")
        .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
        .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
        .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0");

ScenarioBuilder scn = scenario("BasicSimulation")
        .repeat(10)
        .on(
                exec(http("request_1")
                        .get("/computers")));

{
    setUp(scn.injectOpen(atOnceUsers(1))
    ).protocols(httpProtocol);
}
    
}
```

[Screen of Gatling report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCJvh.png)

Here is simulation.log file result:

```
RUN activitydatabase.OneEndpointSimulation  oneendpointsimulation   1647472671275       3.7.5
USER    BasicSimulation START   1647472672290
REQUEST     request_1   1647472672322   1647472672578   OK   
REQUEST     request_1   1647472672614   1647472672740   OK   
REQUEST     request_1   1647472672742   1647472672867   OK   
REQUEST     request_1   1647472672868   1647472672992   OK   
REQUEST     request_1   1647472672994   1647472673121   OK   
REQUEST     request_1   1647472673123   1647472673244   OK   
REQUEST     request_1   1647472673246   1647472673368   OK   
REQUEST     request_1   1647472673371   1647472673492   OK   
REQUEST     request_1   1647472673494   1647472673616   OK   
REQUEST     request_1   1647472673618   1647472673741   OK   
USER    BasicSimulation END 1647472673748
```

Is there any way to speed up the first request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting it wrong, this is expected.

Because of the way your test is designed, the first request takes more time because it has more work to do:

- perform the DNS resolution
- open the HTTP connection

The next requests for this single virtual user will skip this extra work because:

- the DNS resolution will be in cache
- they will reuse the same keep-alive HTTP connection

Comment: So e.g. when I would have my setup like:

`setUp(scn.injectOpen(atOnceUsers(1),
                        rampUsersPerSec(1).to(60).during(60),
                        constantUsersPerSec(60).during(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
                        ).protocols(httpProtocol));`

It means that every request would do this work?

Comment: Assuming you're removing the loop and you're forcing perUserNameResolution (to not use Java's global DNS cache), yes.

Comment: Yes, I would remove the loop. So in that case it means that by default `perUserNameResolution` is switched off, right?